# laravel load vue plugin from vendor package

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I am building a laravel package and in this package I have a vue plugin that I want to import in my project that is using the laravel package.

This is how I try to import it:

```
let MyPlugin = require('./../vendor/laravel-package/src/Plugins/Vue');
Vue.use(MyPlugin, { someOption: true });
```

In this path: `vendor/laravel-package/src/Plugins/Vue/Main.js` I have my plugin:

```
MyPlugin.install = function (Vue, options) {
    console.log(options);
};
```

I am just trying something very simpel:

Now in my console I get the error

> cannot find module

Comment: Do you use laravel mix?

Comment: @SandOfVega Yes I do